# Плагин для хорошего кода, как писать красивый код?

Tags: java, android

Добрый день!

Есть ли хорошие плагины для Android Studio, которые проверяют качество кода? Не правильность выполнения, а именно "красоту" оформления.

Буду благодарна, если посоветуете ресурс, где по полочкам описано как правильно оформлять код (про большие-малые буквы, фигурные скобки и т.д.)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос про плагин. Android Studio довольно неплохо подсвечивает нарушения стиля (и Alt+Enter содержит варианты исправления) и делает некоторые исправления автоматически.

Comment: ctrl+alt+l(win), cmd+alt+l(mac) поможет в форматировании кода.

Comment: Хотя в последней версии студии ctrl на shift заменили, но это не точно.

Comment: Alt+Enter очень помогает при создании новой переменной или функции, но, например, названия он предлагает, простите, дурные (не раскрывающие сути слова или же непонятные сокращения)

Cntl+alt+l хорош, только он исправляет по факту, а не показывает косяки. Его активно использую, но хочется уже сразу писать читаемый и хороший код. 

Это как раз тот момент, когда надо начинать сразу хорошо, потом уже не исправить

Comment: @Alemarika ну в таком случае плагины вам не помогут, вырабатывайте привычку писать красивый читаемый код и пользуйтесь рефакторингом :) 

p.s. В разных компаниях есть разные требования к коду(название переменных, класов и тд).

Comment: За чистотой кода неплохо следят следующие плагины: [FindBugs](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/3847?pr=idea) и [CheckStyle](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1065?pr=idea)/ Второму нужна некоторая [настройка](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/78503/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Style Guide по оформлению кода можно почитать, например, здесь:

[Android Developers: Code Style Guidelines for Contributors](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо, поправил ссылку.

Comment: я тоже поправил, там точка была лишняя )) У меня и с `http` заходит.