# Оформление кода и архитектура приложения Android

Tags: java, android, оформление

В рекомендациях по оформлению кода (в основном просто для *Java*), что я читал, как-то упускают интересующие меня вопросы:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что длинный код в классе *активити* не приветствуется и его следует разбивать на отдельные классы согласно выполняемой задаче?
2. Тогда по какому принципу разбивать код на классы: по принципу выполнения одной небольшой задачи (например, проверка наличия новой информации на сервере) или на комплекс сходных задач выделяется один класс (например, кроме проверки этой информации еще и взайимодействие с ней)?
3. Где должны лежать файлы отдельных классов, там же, где и классы активити или в своей директории?
4. Читал рекомендацию, где говорилось, что вложенные классы неприемлемы, кроме случаев, когда вложенный класс используется только родительским классом. Но в *андроиде* как раз такая ситуация. Только класс *активити* будет пользоваться теми классами, что я пишу для него (вложенные или отдельные).

Не усложнит ли читаемость кода такая разбивка всего кода на классы?

Comment: Это очень большой вопрос. Не думаю, что здесь можно на него ответить. Чтобы узнать и понять ответы, нужно прочитать пару хороших книг по ООП и набить шишек на написании кода. Кроме того, разбиение на классы — это уже не оформление кода, это архитектура приложения. Здорово, что вы этим интересуетесь, конечно.

Comment: Читайте книги и блоги Майера, Харди, Дейтела и проч. признанных специалистов - постепенно понимание придет. В одной статье такое не донести.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, я и так не обхожу стороной рекомендации по оформлению кода и т.д. Сейчас, по ходу изучения, встретился с конкретным вопросом, освещение которого нигде не смог найти, поэтому и хочу получить конкретный ответ: по какому принципу разбивать код, относящийся к какому-либо активити, на классы и нужно ли это вообще делать?

Comment: Ваш вопрос слишком общий, чтобы получить хороший ответ. Думаю при принятии решения о необходимости нового класса вы должны руководствоваться принципами [SOLID](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(объектно-ориентированное_программирование)) . В вашем случае особенную актуальность приобретает "S" - Single responsibility - принцип единственной обязанности. Активити, по сути - контроллер, она должна только управлять данными на представлении (View) и возможно,элементарную логику, которую бессмысленно выносить в отдельный класс. Обработка данных, загрузки\выгрузки и проч. выносится.

Comment: Скорее всего [Вложенный класс](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/innerclass.php) это не то, что вы думаете. Разбивка на классы упростит читаемость кода в силу инкапсуляции, то есть вместо длинной портянки загрузки данных у вас один вызов из класса для загрузки этих данных и сразу понятно с одной строки - загружаем здесь данные. Посмотрите на [структуру API](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/classes.html) самого  Android, сколько здесь разных классов для всевозможных действий. Считайте, что вы дополняете API своими классами, которых там нет. Пользуйтесь ими так же.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос структуру вашей активити, что она делает (достаточно общий алгоритм), чтобы можно было на конкретном примере прояснить интересующий вас вопрос.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/411111/181472

Answer (score 1):

Однозначного ответа нет, но вот есть [рекомендации](https://github.com/futurice/android-best-practices) к разработке. На хабре где-то был перевод этой статьи если с английским туго.

Comment: Пишем красивый код: [ссылка](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/java/mememe.php) Там же есть ссылка для тех, у кого не туго с английским: [англ.ссылка](http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html)

Comment: ЕЩЕ: [Рекомендации к стилю кода](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112042/)

Comment: Спасибо, но все эти ресурсы я уже читал. Не нашел там главного, что меня волнует. А именно это и описал в вопросе: по какому принципу разбивать код, относящийся к какому-либо активити, на классы?